# django choice list menu ajax

Tags: django, jquery

I have this model

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = ((1, u'ADSL'),(2, u'HALO-ISDN'),(3, u'IMS') ..... )

class RequestType(models.Model):
    rCat = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=ADSL)
    rGroup = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True, default='N/A')
    rDesc = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True, default='N/A')
    rDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' `enter code here`% (self.rCat, self.rGroup, self.rDesc)
```

What I want to do is to create a dynamic form from it.

`rCat` is used to Create Categories and `rGroup` is a finer refinement of those categories. What I need is a way to create a drop down choice list from `rCat`  and upon selection of the category to give you a choice to select a `Group`.

After that I need to validate a form and create a new database entry.

Basically form validation and database entry is simple enough what I have is a problem defining and creating a Ajax function that will dynamically filter the choices.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you written the view? It will take a rCat and return rGroups. The form will remain the same as you are doing the same validation. The only difference is that you will dynamically fetch a list of rGroups via javascript/ajax

Comment: well written a view anf forms but the ajax part is the bothersome one